# Select from WITH clause making query Too slow Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]If I am running query, which is within **with entreq_data** it takes max 5 seconds. While executing the whole query with  **select from entreq_data** it takes 120 seconds why? Is with clause makin it slow? Need guidance to improve it. Attaching explain plan also taken from sql developer tool.
[image] 
[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT inner_table.*, ROWNUM rnum
  FROM (

        with entreq_data as(
        SELECT entreq.sys_enterprise_request_id sys_ent_req_id,
             entreq.name ent_req_name,
             NVL(case
                    when regexp_like(UPPER(entreq.name), upper(regexp_replace('MODERN', '\s','|')))
                        then REGEXP_COUNT(entreq.name, regexp_replace('MODERN', '\s','|'),1,'i') * 30
                        + utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(UPPER(regexp_replace(entreq.name,'\W')), UPPER(regexp_replace('MODERN','\W')))
                        - (case when((LEAST(LENGTH('MODERN'),LENGTH(entreq.name))/GREATEST(LENGTH('MODERN'),LENGTH(entreq.name))) >= 0.4)
                        then 0 else ABS(LENGTH('MODERN')-LENGTH(entreq.name))end)

                    else
                        utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(UPPER(regexp_replace(entreq.name,'\W')), UPPER(regexp_replace('MODERN','\W')))
                        - (case when((LEAST(LENGTH('MODERN'),LENGTH(entreq.name))/GREATEST(LENGTH('MODERN'),LENGTH(entreq.name))) >= 0.4)
                        then 0 else ABS(LENGTH('MODERN')-LENGTH(entreq.name))end)
                end,0)
             name_similarity,
             entreq.state ent_req_state,
             userreq.state user_req_state,
             substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1) domain_name,
             NVL(case
                    when regexp_like(UPPER(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)), upper(regexp_replace('one.com', '\s','|')))
                        then REGEXP_COUNT(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1), regexp_replace('one.com', '\s','|'),1,'i') * 30
                        + utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(UPPER(regexp_replace(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1),'\W')), UPPER(regexp_replace('one.com','\W')))
                        - (case when((LEAST(LENGTH('one.com'),LENGTH(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)))/GREATEST(LENGTH('one.com'),LENGTH(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)))) >= 0.4)
                        then 0 else ABS(LENGTH('one.com')-LENGTH(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)))end)

                    else
                        utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(UPPER(regexp_replace(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1),'\W')), UPPER(regexp_replace('one.com','\W')))
                        - (case when((LEAST(LENGTH('one.com'),LENGTH(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)))/GREATEST(LENGTH('one.com'),LENGTH(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)))) >= 0.4)
                        then 0 else ABS(LENGTH('one.com')-LENGTH(substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)))end)
                end,0)
              domain_similarity
              FROM
            cmd_enterprise_request entreq
                  LEFT JOIN
          cmd_user_request userreq ON entreq.name = userreq.enterprise_name
              where entreq.sys_enterprise_request_id != -1 AND ((entreq.state != 'Approved') OR (userreq.state = 'Pending'))

          GROUP BY
              entreq.sys_enterprise_request_id, entreq.name, entreq.state, userreq.state, substr(userreq.email, instr(userreq.email, '@') + 1)
        )
        SELECT entreq_data.sys_ent_req_id, entreq_data.ent_req_name,
             name_similarity,
             domain_similarity,
             entreq_data.ent_req_state, entreq_data.user_req_state,
             CASE
              WHEN name_similarity > domain_similarity
              THEN name_similarity
              ELSE domain_similarity
             END weight,
             CASE
              WHEN name_similarity > domain_similarity
              THEN 'Enterprise Name'
              ELSE 'Email'||' (' || entreq_data.domain_name || ') '
            END matching_attribute
          from entreq_data where ( name_similarity > 80) OR ( domain_similarity > 80)
        ORDER BY name_similarity DESC, domain_similarity DESC
         ) inner_table
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 51
)
 WHERE rnum > 0
```

Comment: 1. The Explain Plan shows the predicate ROWNUM <= 51. There is nothing like that in your query. Are you sure you posted the plan for the query you posted, and not for something else? 2. Are the times you gave us the execution times for the entire query, or just to get the first set of results (perhaps the first 50 rows - whatever setting you have for that in SQL Developer)?

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN PLAN` of both queries in body of post and not as image. Also, how did you time queries? Did you test with *one* run or many runs in same environment (i.e., cpu client and server connection)? Benchmarking should be more than one-off anecdotes.

Comment: @mathguy sorry added complete query

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense. With that said: When you run the query from the WITH clause by itself, do you also limit the results by ROWNUM <= 51? If so, you are comparing apples to oranges. See how long it takes to get ALL the results from the subquery (in the WITH clause) - and I do mean all of them, not just the first screen of results in SQL Developer. You will see it's a lot more than 5 seconds.

Comment: @Parfait attached execution plan for sub query, which is within with entreq_data. I run both query on same environment. I just mentioned time showing in sql develper tool.

Comment: @mathguy When you run the query from the WITH clause by itself, do you also limit the results by ROWNUM <= 51?  No. Actually query in with clause without ROWNUM<=51 taking less time than the original query. Also attached explain plan for subquery.

Comment: @Parfait No i am telling the subquery which is inside WITH, it will run fine without error.

Comment: @mathguy I have attached two explain plan **1st** complete query with ROWNUM<=51 and **2nd** subquery without  ROWNUM<=51. Here subquery mean query inside WITH clause.

Comment: @Parfait I have attached two explain plan **1st** complete query with ROWNUM<=51 and **2nd** subquery without  ROWNUM<=51. Here subquery mean query inside WITH clause.

Comment: Please post the non-WITH version of query. From comment below, is pagination framework applied to this version as well? Can you test both queries outside of any UI framework? This may isolate the framework effect and show no real difference between queries. Better yet, test both queries outside of SQL Developer, like SQL*Plus command line or via application layer like Java, Python, etc.

Comment: @Parfait added **without ROWNUM condition.png** this is where removed ROWNUM<=51 condition

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what is going on. Let's see if this helps.

Suppose the subquery in the WITH clause would return 10 million rows, were it not for the ROWNUM limit.

If you run the query in the WITH clause by itself, with the ROWNUM <= 51 limit, then you will get the first 51 rows. Importantly, the Jarko-Winkler scores will only be computed 51 times (or 102 times if it's two scores per row).

When you run the combined query, to get the first 51 rows that satisfy the extra conditions on the Jarko-Winkler scores, the WITH clause may have to output 500 rows (because only 51 of them satisfy the extra conditions). Even though many rows are discarded, the scores must still be computed - and that's the most expensive part of running the query. Now the scores are computed for 500 rows, even though only 51 rows survive in the output.

Comment: **If you run the query in the WITH clause by itself, with the ROWNUM <= 51 limit**:No I attached explain plan where this condition is not applied, so i mean inner query running very fast without ROWNUM<=51. I need to mention that, this ROWNUM get automatically gets added by the framework i use so i don't have control on it.Basically this framework aumatically apply pagination when the query gets executed from the the UI report. So basically i have written query other that ROWNUM condtion, ROWNUM<=51 is applied automatically the framework as part of pagination.

Comment: I have attached two explain plan 1st complete query with ROWNUM<=51 and 2nd subquery without  ROWNUM<=51.

Comment: @pankaj - That "pagination" thing is what I was referring to when I mentioned that SQL Developer may show you the first 50 (or first 200) rows in 5 seconds, but that's not the time to run the **entire** query (returning over 50 thousand rows). Talking here only about the (sub)query in the WITH clause.

Comment: added  **https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKxUL.png** this is where removed ROWNUM<=51 condition only.

Comment: **That "pagination" thing is what I was referring to when I mentioned that SQL Developer may show you the first 50 (or first 200) rows in 5 seconds:** But i am running  the sub query in the WITH clause without ROWNUM<=50 and its working faster. And as i am running this query without ROWNUM<=50 so its returning big data (may be over 50 thousand rows).

Comment: @pankaj - Are you seeing all 50,000+ rows, and after you are seeing them all, you see the timing of 5 seconds?

Comment: One point to consider is that in the rownum query you are ordering by fields. This isnt done in the with_block. Those fields you are ordering by use the function of jaro_winkler which i assume contributes to the slowness

Comment: hmmm not exactly, actually sql developer returns 50 rows only so this time is for 50 rows only (and it varies from 3 to 5 secs), and gets loaded more rows  while scrolling down. But original query returns actual(final) results where it has 37 rows only by taking 120 to 160 secs.

Comment: @mathguy Seems now i am getting your point, the actual query is slow because it loads complete results first, but the question is, how to make the real query faster. should  i replace left join with something?

Comment: The original query doenst have a filter predicate on the "name_similarity>80", which is the reason why you dont have a "filter" criteria with the jaro_winkler fuctions in your first query. As @mathguy says, it is that which most likely is the cause for the slowness.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph but how to add filter predicate on the "name_similarity>80" in the orginal query? Because oracle will not allow WHERE clause on name_similarity alias.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Since using name_similarity  or domain_similarity alias is not allowed in with WHERE clause in oracle.This is the main rason i have taken the query in WITH clause.

Comment: @pankaj - the WITH subquery returns about 52 thousand rows (at least that's what the explain plan **estimates**). The JW score must be computed for all 52k rows, and there is no workaround, since you want to retrieve rows where one of the scores is greater than 80. It doesn't matter how you change the query, those 52k x 2 JW score computations have to be completed, and that (very likely) accounts for 95% or more of the execution time. No rewriting of the query will make the JW score computation faster. And by that I mean, even if you could use JW score in the WHERE clause, that wouldn't help.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you for your inputs. Don't i have any option, to increase its performance? Because if the query is taking approx 3mins to fetch the records for 52k rows, in future it will be slower if number of rows will increase. And is the JW is only reason of its slowness?